# Cosine of a matrix

Tags: matrices

I came across this question, asked in a competitive exam. It  is as follows.

Given a matrix M = \begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix} what is the value of cos(πM/6)?

I've tried series expansion but I think there is an alternative way doing it, any help is appreciated.

Options given are

\begin{bmatrix}1/2&1\\1&1/2\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt3/4&-\sqrt3/4\\-\sqrt3/4&\sqrt3/4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt3/4&\sqrt3/4\\\sqrt3/4&\sqrt3/4\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1/2&\sqrt3/2\\\sqrt3/2&1/2\end{bmatrix}

Comment: did you try diagonalizing $M$?

Comment: But still, it would contain a pi factor right, but the options does not have them at all, may be I am making a mistake, please help me out.

Comment: No one can tell if you make a mistake if you do not show us what you did.....

Comment: http://infohost.nmt.edu/~iavramid/notes/mp2-5.pdf page 58

Comment: Observe that $\cos M=A^{-1}\cos(AMA^{-1})A$. So we can reduce to a diagonal form.

Comment: `@ John Ma` diagonalization should leave the off diagonal entries zero, even after doing the power series expansion of cosine, right. Multiplying with `\pi /6` is going to introduce a `\pi ^2` term in the power series expansion, but none of the options contains a '\pi' factor in them, this was my doubt.

Comment: Your intuition does not make sense since the series is infinite. For example we have $$0=\sin \pi = \pi - \frac{\pi^3}{3!} + \frac{\pi^5}{5!} - \frac{\pi^7}{7!} + \cdots $$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear from the question whether you are looking for the series expansion solution or an alternative.

For the series expansion, remember that

$$\cos(M) = I - \frac{M^2}{2!} + \frac{M^4}{4!} - ...$$

and that $M^n$ can be found by diagonalising.

An alternative solution has been given in part by user akhmeteli on the Physics SE.

It is easy to show that $3$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ with eigenvector $\left( \begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix} \right)$. By virtue of the series expansion, we know that this is an eigenvector of $\cos(\frac{\pi M}{6})$ and so the corresponding eigenvalue is $\cos(\frac{\pi 3}{6}) = 0$. Thus we are looking for a matrix with determinant $0$ and with an eigenvalue (corresponding to our eigenvector) of $0$. Only one of the solutions satisfies this condition.